# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Send failure: Connection was reset (RStudio.cloud)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, httr

I want to get the *id_product* and *id_parent* from this web page.
Yesterday, I could get the results, but when I tried it again today I got an error message. Anyway, I'm doing it from **rstudio.cloud**.

```
url <-  paste("https://www.tokopedia.com/zhafranseafood/cumi-asin-1kg-per-pack")

    headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
    doc <- read_html(httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(.headers=headers)))%>%
          html_text()
    id_product <- str_match_all(doc,'product_id\\s+=\\s+(\\d+);')[[1]][,2]
    id_parent <- str_match_all(doc,'parent_id\\s+=\\s+(\\d+);')[[1]][,2]

    id_product
    id_parent
```

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Send failure: Connection was reset
```

I've been trying to search for the possible explanation but is still to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extra header is required by server

```
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

headers = c(
  'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0',
  'Accept' = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'
)

doc <- read_html(httr::GET(url = 'https://www.tokopedia.com/zhafranseafood/cumi-asin-1kg-per-pack', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers)))%>%
       html_text()

id_product <- str_match_all(doc,'product_id\\s+=\\s+(\\d+);')[[1]][,2]
id_parent <- str_match_all(doc,'parent_id\\s+=\\s+(\\d+);')[[1]][,2]

id_product
id_parent
```

Comment: I still could not do it. It's loading like forever. Anyway, I'm doing it from **rstudio.cloud**.

Comment: I'm unsure what difference that makes. I ran the above from R Studio just fine.  Open this url in brower `https://www.tokopedia.com/zhafranseafood/cumi-asin-1kg-per-pack` and inspect the web-traffic for it. Look at the headers which are used in the initial request. Re-create the entire set first and see what happens. In your case it might turn out that something else is going on but for me it was that the server wanted that second header.